# Managing stock in WooCommerce for made to order products from an overall quantity of raw material?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

We run a perfume store - pellwall.com - in addition to selling complete, manufactured fragrances ready to buy off the shelf a large part of our business is selling individual ingredient components for people to design and make perfume.

The final fragrances are easy to manage for stock as we make up batches of them and store a specific number of them.

The chemicals are difficult to manage stock and it's crucial we are able to do so as we have roughly around 800 of these products. We sell the chemicals in 10ml, 30ml, 50ml, 100ml, 200, 500ml, 1kg, 2kg and 5kg. But we don't have these on the shelf ready to send out, they are made to order when an order comes in from a barrel or drum of the chemical.

So for example we will have a 200kg drum of a chemical and when an order comes in for 1kg we would decant 1kg and ship that etc.

We need to be able to say to WooCommerce that we have XXXkg of this product, and have it deduct the variations sold.

Our chemical products have a 'bottle size' attribute that defines the size being selected.

We have tried a number of plugins to achieve this and extensive research but can't find an explanation of how to achieve this. It must be possible as I would imagine it works on a similar basis to how fruit and veg store may operate.

I have even tried some custom scripting and API access to deduct stock sold from a Google Sheet but it is messy and often incorrect.

I'd ideally not like to use a plugin for this so one option we could explore is to post to an external script the size of an ingredient everytime it sells. I could work with that.

Can anyone point me to any resources that may help guide me to a solution or offer help themselves?